# Event Receiver AfterProperties not setting when item adding in code

Tags: 2010, event-receivers

I have an event receiver that sets a value of a field using `properties.AfterProperties` within `ItemAdding`.

This works fine when adding a folder (with a custom content type) within the browser (the content type might not be set at that point but the value is in the field), but when adding a folder via code (`list.RootFolder.SubFolders.Add("some folder name")` or via PowerShell, or even Client Object Model code), the event receiver fires but the value isn't being saved into the field.

Anyone else see this? I should mention it's within a Document Library.

SharePoint build number is: 14.0.7015.1000

Reproduction steps: Team Site with Shared Documents, custom column added called "TestColumn".

Event Receiver Code to reproduce:

```
/// <summary>
/// List Item Events
/// </summary>
public class TestReceiver : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An item is being added.
    /// </summary>
    public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdding(properties);

        if (properties.List.Title == "Shared Documents")
        {
            properties.AfterProperties["TestColumn"] = "Foo";
        }
    }        
}
```

PowerShell to reproduce:

```
$w = get-spweb http://sitecoll/
$w.Lists["Shared Documents"].RootFolder.SubFolders.Add("TestFolder").Update()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With thanks to Max Melcher, I found this workaround for creating Folders that writes AfterProperties to the item:

```
$w = get-spweb http://redacted
$list = $w.Lists["Shared Documents"]
$f= $list.AddItem("", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder, "test 2")
$f.Update()
```

Comment: glad it worked out.